# Extra column still showing in Datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I can't seem to get rid of the extra "column" in this Datagrid... don't quite know what I'm doing wrong?

```
<StackPanel Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                                                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                                                          CanContentScroll="True"
                                                          utils:TopMouseScrollPriorityBehavior.TopMouseScrollPriority="True">
                                                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="SDataGrid" 
                                                              Grid.Row="1" RowHeaderWidth="0" 
                                                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                                              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                                                              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                                                              ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource HeaderStyle}">
                                                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                                                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="" MinWidth="40" x:Name="SId" />
                                                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" MinWidth="100" x:Name="SName" />
                                                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Colour" Width="*" x:Name="SColour" />
                                                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                                                </DataGrid>
                                            </ScrollViewer>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </StackPanel>


<Style x:Key="HeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Polour}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Solour}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Solour}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource Gott}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
</Style>
```

For some reason I just can't get the little bit at the end of the header to disappear and for the last "Colour" column to stretch all the way. I want it to horizontally stretch... this issue doesn't appear when it's centered..

Comment: thanks man, let me know which one was causing the problem if you can :) i'm gonna try and see how this looks now :)

Comment: just tried removing the stackp/grid/scrollviewer and it still doesn't work. The width of Colour column is set to * originally so... not sure what else i have to do :\

Comment: Width="*" with the ScrollViewer commented out works. HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" is what is causing the issue.

Comment: hmm.. commented out the scrollviewer,and also removed the scrollviewer properties in the datagrid... still doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Will Setting the ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" instead of "Hidden" work?

```
    <StackPanel Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                              CanContentScroll="True">
                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="SDataGrid"
                              Grid.Row="1" RowHeaderWidth="0"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                              ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource HeaderStyle}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="" MinWidth="40" x:Name="SId" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" MinWidth="100" x:Name="SName" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Colour" Width="*" x:Name="SColour" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Sadly it makes no difference.... the last column is still way smaller than the actual text. It's showing "Col" and cutting off the "our" :(